# Map interface for Android Application

Tags: android, android-mapview

Currently, I am working on the development of an application for Android devices, which will include indoor tracking and routing.

On the one hand, the administrator of this application will upload an image of the map, so users' locations will be projected on this map. On the other hand, a user will be able to zoom in/out, navigate the map, get information and other similar actions that are available on the Google Map Services.

I have been reading in the Android API documentation and I came across MapView. Even though MapView is a complete and robust library, it is not going to help me since it makes use of the Google Maps Service.

My question is whether another (similar) API exists for viewing and managing a Map, besides the MapView.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: what would be the format of the map file that the admin would upload to the server..

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213152/override-mapview-tile-source

Comment: Thank you very much. I am working with mapsforge atm. Can I ask where can I find sample .map files for testing my applications?